# Delete Button not deleting items in ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

Through the answers and help on a previous question. I have now come across another issue.

My btnDelete_MouseClick() event is not deleting the customer information that is stored in the textBox's.

I want it to take in the info like: Ashton Smith 864123456789

And then when the exact same info is in the corresponding textFields and I hit the `delete` button it removes it from the listBox.

This is what I have so far. It runs but it does not delete the customer from the listBox.

---

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Customer cust;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tbxFirstName.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
        tbxFirstName.MaxLength = 35; 
        tbxLastName.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
        tbxLastName.MaxLength = 35;
        tbxPhone.MaxLength = 10;
        listBoxDatabase.Name = "CUSTOMERS";
    }

    private void btnAddCustomer_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //string customer = tbxFirstName.Text + " " + tbxLastName.Text + " " + tbxPhone.Text;
        cust = new Customer(tbxFirstName.Text, tbxLastName.Text, tbxPhone.Text);


        if (listBoxDatabase.Items.Cast<Customer>().Any(x => x.ToString() == cust.ToString()))
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Customer Already Exist!", "ERROR");
        }
        else
        {
            listBoxDatabase.Items.Add(cust);
        }
    }

    private void btnDelete_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Customer custToDelete = listBoxDatabase.Items.Cast<Customer>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToString() == cust.ToString());

        if (custToDelete != null)
        {
            listBoxDatabase.Items.Remove(cust);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Customer Found!", "ERROR");
        }
    }

    private void listBoxDatabase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBoxDatabase.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            Customer cust = listBoxDatabase.Items[listBoxDatabase.SelectedIndex] as Customer;
            tbxFirstName.Text = cust.getFirstName;
            tbxLastName.Text = cust.getLastName;
            tbxPhone.Text = cust.getPhone;
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: is the customer being deleted from listBoxDatabase ?

Comment: Aren't you missing an event listener for your mouse clicks?

Comment: No it is not being deleted from the listBox either @Forlani

Comment: @Aliminator no I am using the on MouseClick and the add button works perfectly fine but the delete button is not.

Comment: is custToDelete always null?

Comment: It should not be. But even if it were, I should still be getting the MessageBox to pop up in the else statement correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You logic for deletion is wrong. You should not use `.ToString()` to compare objects. You can Cast the Selected Item of the ListBox to your specific type and then Remove that from the items collection:

```
Customer selected = listBoxDatabase.SelectedItem as Customer;
if(selected != null)
   listBoxDatabase.Items.Remove(selected);
else
   MessageBox.Show("No Customer Found!", "ERROR");
```

Comment: does this code replace my entire method or simply the code within the if statement? Thank you for your help!

Comment: There were some errors (you have Select instead of selected!) but you were right. This works. Thank you :)